# General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value while doing update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I faced the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value.

It happens when I try to update amount of `views` on specific `post`.
I've just set default value of points while initializing it specified in the model in `$attributes` table.

Posts table migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('text');
            $table->integer('points');
            $table->bigInteger('views');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('is_closed');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }
```

Post model:

```
    const POINTS = 0;
    const VIEWS = 0;
    const IS_CLOSED = 0;

    protected $attributes = [
        'points' => self::POINTS,
        'views' => self::VIEWS,
        'is_closed' => self::IS_CLOSED,
        'title' => null,
        'text' => null,
        'user_id' => null,
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'text',
        'user_id',
    ];
```

My Service where I try to increment the value of `views`:

```
public function incrementPostViews($id)
    {
        $post = $this->post->findOrFail($id);
        $post->views++;
        return $post->save();
    }
```

I did use the `Request` rule but only while creating new `post`:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => ['required', 'max:50'],
            'text' => ['required', 'max:1000'],
            'user_id' => ['numeric', 'nullable'],
        ];
    }
```

So by default the `points`, `views` and `is_closed` fields are set to 0 while creating new `Post`. To be honest I do not have any ideas why it is causing an error.

**Update:**

In `Post` model I've changed the `$attributes` array and added `title`, `text` and `user_id` which default value is set to `null`. Those three fields stays in `$fillable` array also. I'm not sure if it's the right way to fix it. If it's not, please correct me.

In the `migration` there are not changes made.

All changes are visible above.

Comment: Your SQL table definition requires that the column `title` has a value. You need to give a definition or **ensure** that whatever data you're inserting ALWAYS has a `title` value. I don't know how to do this in Laravel.

Comment: I've made an update in the question.

Comment: @kalview the `title` should be *nullable* on DB level as well.

Comment: @ths can you explain why? While adding new Post I would rather stay with `required` in request `rules()`

Comment: @kalview that depends on your app logic, whether the `title` is required or not. What i couldn't understand from your code is why you override the `attributes` property of your model ?

Comment: @ths I want to set it to default values after adding new Post, so I declare it in the `attribues` array. You mean doubling them also in `fillable`?

Comment: The `attributes` property is not meant to be changed or even touched by the developer as it is heavily used by `Eloquent` internally. Instead, you should consider using [`Eloquent Mutators`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to set default values. Anyway, unless the default value is not *complex* you should set it on the `DB` level instead.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it. I know I could do it right in Controller or Service setting values like `Post::create(['views'=>0]);` but I wanted to avoid this approach and try something else.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your `title` item as `required` in your table but you didn't declare a default value. And your insert operation doesn't give a value for that column, so it fails.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to declare `title` as `nullable` instead.

But if you have a good reason to make it `required`, you'll have to revisit the way you insert your rows so you can offer a value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

You must create THE post first, once that post has been created you can then update its attributes.

```
 $user = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'text' => $request->text,
        'points' => 0,
        'views' => 0,
        'is_closed' => $request->is_closed,
       
    ]);
```

Comment: It's about the updating current existing data in DB. Please read carefully.